# Using multiple entries for reactjs SPA

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have following configuration

[image: I have following configuration in my]

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config = {
    entry: 
    {
        'index':SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
        'home':SRC_DIR + "/app/home.js",
        'profile':SRC_DIR + "/app/profile.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + '/app',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "common",
            chunks: ["index", "home","profile"]
        })],
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader", 
                query:{
                    presets:['react','es2015','stage-2'],
                }
            }
        ]
    },
     devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Now, I want to load `common.bundle + index.bundle` in case of index.js, `common.bundle + profile.bundle` in case of profile.js and so on.

I have only one index.html file, I want to load these three bundles separately whenever corresponding url is hit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reactjs Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <div id="app"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script src="/app/index.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible with only one `index.html` file? Do I need more than one html?

Comment: maybe using `ejs` with `htmlWebpackPlugin` can help? or myabe consider working with `DllPlugin`

Comment: I think your possible solution could be lazy loading feature of webpack. check this out https://medium.com/@Nadav.Dav/implementing-lazy-loading-with-webpack-and-react-router-f8497f895892

Comment: @Sag1v Let me check these features.